# No consigo traer un dato de mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un problema, quiero traer de la bbdd en mysql phpmyadmin un nombre que esta almacenado allí, quiero que al logearme me lleve al index y me aparezca mi nombre, el problema que tengo es que no me funciona, me sale como que no me ha funcionado la query, a ver si me podeis ayudar:
login.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dansa - Login</title>
</head>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
        <input name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        require "connect_db.php";
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];
        $spass = md5($pass);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE email = '".$email."' AND passwd = '".$spass."'";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {
                $conn->close();
                echo "<p>Se ha logeado correctamente</p>";
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE email = '".$email."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];               
                $conn->close();
                header('Location: http://www.dansa.cf');
            } else {
                echo "<p>El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos</p>";
            }


    } ?>
```

y esto donde se imprime, el header.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<header><nav>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='index.html'><i class='fas fa-home'></i>Inicio</a></li>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='equipo.html'><i class='fas fa-users'></i>Equipo</a></li>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='departamentos.html'><i class='fas fa-pencil-ruler'></i>Proyectos</a></li>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='news.html'><i class='fas fa-exclamation'></i>Novedades</a></li>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='contacto.html'><i class='fas fa-envelope'></i>Contacto</a></li>";
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == TRUE){
        echo "<li class='nav_elemento' style='margin-left:auto;'><a href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-user'></i>Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
        <li class='nav_elemento'><a href='signup.php'><i class='fas fa-user'></i>Registrarse</a></li></a></nav></header>";
    } else {
        echo "<li class='nav_elemento' style='margin-left:auto;'><a href='#'>";
        print_r ($_SESSION['name']);
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li class='nav_elemento' style='margin-left:auto;'><a href='cerrar-sesion.php'><i class='fas fa-user'></i>Cerrar Sesión</a></li></header>";
    }

?>
```

Me funciona todo el header y el logearme y las sesiones tambien, lo que pasa es que en la segunda query, la de seleccionar el name de la tabla no lo consigo hacer bien, no se porque.
Mi base de datos esta compuesta por la tabla de usuarios y 5 columnas (id, timestamp, name, email, pass)
Asi que pido solo name y me lo deberia devolver, no se porque es tan complicado o no me funciona, si necesitais mas datos decirme, me corre prisa.

Comment: Porque estas haciendo 2 querys? si con el primero ya traes todo, ademas, estas cerrando tu conexión, lo que puede causar el error

Comment: Aparte de la doble consulta innecesaria, si estás usando resultados sin buffer `num_rows` no devuelve el número de filas hasta que no se hayan leído todas las filas, así que en ese caso, hay que usar `store_result` antes. Puedes leer el apartado **Descripción** en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) así como [esta nota de contribución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289).